# Specify header for SectionProperty in OpenXml

Tags: c#, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk, sections

I am changing an existing docx file by appending new sections/paragraphs/other content. (Basically, the existing file is empty besides having an empty paragraph and a header/footer in it. The idea is to use this as a template.)

I am adding the new content like this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceDocx, true))
        {
            var headerPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
            headerPart.Header = new Header(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Hallo"))));
            string headerId = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);

            Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            RemoveLastEmptyParagraph(body);

            //var sectionProperties = body.Elements<SectionProperties>();
            //foreach (var section in sectionProperties)
            //{
            //  section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();
            //}

            var firstsection = body.GetFirstChild<SectionProperties>();
            var defaultPageSize = firstsection.Descendants<PageSize>().FirstOrDefault();
            var pageMargins1 = firstsection.Descendants<PageMargin>().FirstOrDefault();

            body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("A4"))));
            body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new ParagraphProperties(CreateSectionBreak(null, defaultPageSize, pageMargins1))));

            body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("A3"))));
            body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new ParagraphProperties(CreateSectionBreakA3(headerId))));

            body.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("A4"))));

        }
    private static void RemoveLastEmptyParagraph(Body body)
    {
        Paragraph lastParagraph = null;
        foreach (var element in body.ChildElements)
        {
            if (element is Paragraph paragraph)
            {
                lastParagraph = paragraph;
            }
        }

        lastParagraph?.Remove();
    }

    private SectionProperties CreateSectionBreak(string headerId, PageSize pageSize, PageMargin margins)
    {
        var section = new SectionProperties();

        if (headerId != null)
        {
            section.AddChild(new HeaderReference() { Id = headerId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default });
        }

        section.AddChild(new SectionType { Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage });
        section.AddChild((PageSize)pageSize.Clone());
        section.AddChild((PageMargin)margins.Clone());

        return section;
    }

    private SectionProperties CreateSectionBreakA3(string headerId)
    {
        if (headerId == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(headerId));

        var pageSize = new PageSize();
        pageSize.Width = (UInt32)(42.0 * 566.92556267362);
        pageSize.Height = (UInt32)(29.7 * 566.92556267362);
        pageSize.Orient = new EnumValue<PageOrientationValues>(PageOrientationValues.Landscape);

        var margin = new PageMargin();
        margin.Top = (Int32)(1.0 * 566.92556267362);
        margin.Left = (Int32)(1.0 * 566.92556267362);
        margin.Right = (Int32)(1.0 * 566.92556267362);
        margin.Bottom = (Int32)(1.0 * 566.92556267362);
        margin.Header = (Int32)(1.0 * 566.92556267362);
        margin.Footer = (Int32)(1.0 * 566.92556267362);

        return CreateSectionBreak(headerId, pageSize, margin);
    }
```

However, the new/changed header never show up in the second section. When looking at the docx file using the ProductivityTool, i can see the header reference is part of the SectionProperty - but it's simply not displayed in word. Word is using the pre-existing header for all 3 sections in the document.

I already tried removing all HeaderReference instances from the document before setting the new one (outcommented code), but that didn't help: Word would not show any header at all in this case. So it seems i'm adding the "new" one in the wrong way somehow. Unfortunately every single example dealing with headers is working with documents that only have one header. I couldn't find one that is dealing with headers that are only used within specific sections.

Any ideas how to set a HeaderReference for a SectionProperty correctly?

Answer (score 1):

So, basically, the problem is a SectionProperties instance that word places directly underneath the body element as a first child. As long as this is part of the document, all the other elements are ignored. One needs to remove this instance (e.b.: After the call to RemoveLastEmptyParagraph()) like this:

```
            var sectionProperties = body.Elements<SectionProperties>().Last(); 
            body.RemoveChild(sectionProperties);
```

Soon as this has been removed the added headers are displayed in words. Incase one wants to have the "default" headers (that vanish once the SectionProperties has been removed) back for the end of the document, one can simply add the removed SectionProperties to the end of the body as the last child.